# Return number of months and years from int?

Tags: sql-server

This seems pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If i have a number of months, like `61`
That is 5 years and 1 month. 
How can I write a select to give me the value of `0105`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some `case` , `cast` , `/12` and `%12`:

```
declare @value int
set @value=61
select 
case when len(cast(@value%12 as int))=1 then '0'+cast(@value%12 as varchar(1)) else cast(cast(@value%12 as int)as varchar(2)) end+
case when len(cast(@value/12 as int))=1 then '0'+cast(@value/12 as varchar(1)) else cast(cast(@value/12 as int)as varchar(2)) end
```

**output:** `0105`

Comment: WOW! Some great answers! Thank you all for the input!

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you're going to have a query like this:

```
SELECT MONTHS
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

You could do some division and get the number of years:

```
SELECT MONTHS / 12 AS YEARS
FROM   MY_TABLE;
```

Next, you need to get the number of months remaining from that. [Modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) mathematical operations are used for this:

```
SELECT MONTHS % 12 AS MONTHS,
       MONTHS / 12 AS YEARS
FROM   MY_TABLE;
```

Now you'll need to [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) [it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634206.aspx):

```
SELECT FORMAT(MONTHS % 12 AS MONTHS, '00'),
       FORMAT(MONTHS / 12 AS YEARS, '00')
FROM   MY_TABLE;
```

Finally, concat the two results together:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(MONTHS % 12 AS MONTHS, '00'),
              FORMAT(MONTHS / 12 AS YEARS, '00')) AS RESULT
FROM   MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: `'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.` for versions `lower than 2014`

Comment: [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is supported in SQL Server **2012** and above.

Comment: Your version did output **0501** instead of the desired **0105** so I took the liberty to fix it.

Comment: @Farhęg Gotcha.. Not all that familiar with SQL Server, but thanks for your input.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks for the edit. I was quickly trying to answer, so I could go home.

Comment: @Filburt, ohhh my mistake, I meant **2012**

Answer (score 1):

Here You have two possible solutions:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 61

SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(Month,@n,'2000-01-01'),1),'/',''),4)

SELECT RIGHT(CAST(10000+@n%12*100+@n/12 AS VARCHAR(5)),4)
```